# 140 Characters, is that a string or text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am just doing a quick scaffold on rails, and I'm going to have a field that's only 140 characters or less, is that a string or text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be a `string`.

A good rule of thumb would be to use `string` for anything up to 255 characters. Beyond that, use a `text`